# How to count values for one id in table and put data to other table sql

Tags: sql

I have problem with summing values... Tables are presenting like this:

```
create table clients
    (
      id_c    INTEGER not null,
      name    VARCHAR2(20),
      age     INTEGER,
      address VARCHAR2(20),
      price number,
      Primary key (id_c)
    );

create table PRODUCTS
    (
      id_p              NUMBER not null,
      name_product      VARCHAR2(30),
      price             NUMBER,
      duration          NUMBER,
      primary key (id_p)
    );

create table TRANSACTIONS
    (
      id_t NUMBER not null,
      id_c NUMBER not null,
      id_p NUMBER not null,
      td_c NUMBER,
      primary key (ID_t),
      foreign key (ID_c) references CLIENTS (ID_c)
    );
```

now i want to sum up all costs of products (translations.td_c) for each client (translations.id_c), and put that value to table clients into price row. The point is to take the same ID of client (ID_C) and sum up every row that have that ID_C in transactions table, sum up for that client every value of td_c, and put it into table clients to price column... I don't know how to do that, every time when i trying to make some UPDATE code, there are errors...

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, twice.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff For example i make something like this 
`update clients c
set c.price= (select Sum(t.td_c) 
                    from translations t
                    where t.id_c=p.id_c);`
but it doesnt works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a subquery:

```
UPDATE clients
       SET price = (SELECT sum(transactions.td_c)
                           FROM transactions
                           WHERE transactions.id_c = clients.id_c);
```

But your design is probably problematic. `clients.price` entirely depends on `transactions` and therefore shouldn't exist materialized like that.

I'll immediately go out of sync, if there are any changes in `transactions`. E.g., if you insert a new row into transactions for some customer "John" with an `td_c` of +100, the `price` for "John" in the clients table will be a 100 short until you update it again.

Consider using a view to have the `price` and the client data joined, always selecting the current `price` from `transactions`. E.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW clients_with_price
AS
SELECT c.id_c,
       c.name,
       c.age,
       c.address,
       s.price
       FROM clients c
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(t.td_c) price,
                              t.id_c
                              FROM transactions t
                              GROUP BY t.id_c) s
                      ON s.id_c = c_id.c;
```

Then drop the `price` column in `clients`.

Comment: @ticky bit That helped, but i don't get the problem with sync, can you tell me what you suggest some changes?

Comment: @Potato: I added an example to my answer.